# Spring configuration files: package imports or names in attribute values

Tags: java, xml, spring, namespaces

All the examples I've seen so far about Spring configuration have

```
<bean class = "org.example.complex.package.path.FooClass" >
```

I wonder if this can be simplified through a mechanism similar to Java imports, something like:

```
<beans ...>
  <import name = "org.example.complex.package.path.FooClass" />
  <import name = "org.example.another-package.*" />

  <bean class = "FooClass" >...</bean>
  <bean class = "AnotherClass">...</bean>
</beans>
```

Alternatively (or in addition), does XML support namespaces in attribute values? Something like:

```
<beans xmlns:foo="org.example.complex.package.path." ...>
  <bean class = "foo:FooClass" ...>
  ...
```

I would need this for other purposes too (e.g., working with RDF's URIs). My understanding is that this is supported by some software, but not a standard XML feature.

Comment: Why don't you simply annotate your beans, and use component-scan: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-autodetection

Comment: While that's very good to know (thank you!), I still would like to configure via XML, cause I've to set parameters and it's not so easy via component scanning.

Answer (score 0):

No way. Spring uses `import` tag to import / add another beans definition xml file to the current context.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that. Of course I'm talking about a different type of import.